# Which airports have ILS Cat IIIC?

Tags: landing, airport, regulations, ils, visibility

Are there any airports with ILS working CATIIIC?

What do the charts for this procedure look like? Is there a missed approach procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not implemented anywhere in the world.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#ILS_categories):

> As of 2012 this category is not yet in operation anywhere in the world
>   as it requires guidance to taxi in zero visibility as well. Category
>   IIIc is not mentioned in EU-OPS.

[Airliners](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/105924/):

> As far as I know NO airport in the world currently offers catIIIc as
>   it has the most ridiculous minima both in the horizontal and vertical
>   plane ...

Comment: "In operation" and "implemented" are two different things. The second link suggest that many airports have the equipment installed to do a IIIc landing (although not IIIc taxiing), as it's similar/the same equipment from the airport end

Comment: Your "Airliners" source is not realiable since the explanation belongs to the year 2004, aprox. (http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=742695)

Answer (score 4):

There would still need to be a missed approach procedure, since plenty of things besides "not seeing the runway/lights" can cause the need for a go-around: equipment malfunction, traffic on the runway, winds shifting out of limits, etc.  So no matter how "good" the approach is, it still has to have a defined missed approach procedure.

That procedure might well mirror the Cat I missed approach instructions.  Not certainly, but they often do.